# How to select distinct JSON array from MySQL regardless for the order?

Tags: mysql, json

I have a JSON column which only stores array like this

```
| ids       |
| --------- |
| [1,2,3]   |
| [1,2]     |
| [1,3]     |
| [1,2,3]   |
| [1]       |
| [2]       |
| [2,1,3]   |
| [2,3,1]   |
| [2,3]     |
| [3,1]     |
```

basically I want to have a output look like this

```
| ids       |
| --------- |
| [1,2,3]   |
| [1,2]     |
| [1,3]     |
| [1]       |
| [2]       |
| [2,3]     |
```

orders do not matter but size in this case, but size of the array and elements in them matters. For instance,  `[1]`, `[1,2]` and `[1,2,3]` are three distinct arrays, but `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` are the same so regardless which one to select.

I'm currently using MySQL 8.0.33

I've been looking at `JSON_TABLE()` but I don't have a clue where to start.

Comment: Why store data un-normalized like this in the first place? You will have to get sorted states of each row and then go distinct on them. Sorting this json array doesn't seem to have any straightforward functions [`here`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html). It can involve using procedures, json_table() etc

Comment: JSON_TABLE, GROUP_CONCAT(ORDER BY), DISTCINT.